# Need Validation on html dropdownlist with data from Viewbag

Tags: html, asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I know I'm not supposed to use the Viewbag and that I should build a menu using `Html.DropDowlListFor()` so that i can add attribute bound to the members of the model, BUT, that would involve a pretty extensive code rewrite....

I have a custom controller with a menu:

***.ASCX**

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("CityIDs", new SelectList(ViewBag.cities, "Id", "Name"), "--Select--", new { style = "width:200px" })%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("CityIDs") %>
```

The List populates just fine and I can default to the top item to `"--Select--"`
The prbolem is that I want the validation error to occur on anything that is not from the viewbag.... how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Validation for dropdown lists only ensures that *something* was posted. If you want to ensure that the value that was posted is actually one of a set of "allowed" values, then you'll have to manually do that in your post action:

```
var cityIds = db.Cities.Select(m => m.Id);
if (!cityIds.Contains(model.CityIDs))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("CityIDs", "You must select one of the available choices.");
}

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ...
```

Two things:

1. Notice that I'm pulling the city ids straight from the database (the actual code you'd need here, of course, depends on your specific implementation). The important thing, though, is that `ViewBag` only survives a single request, so you can't look for them in `ViewBag` after posting.
2. Despite the pluralized name of `CityIDs`, using the `DropDownList` helper ensures that only a single selected value will exist. If this is actually supposed to be a multiselect, then you need to use `ListBox` instead, and update this conditional here to account for check for multiple values.

Comment: CityIDs is just a single select.. ok I'll try these ideas...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Populates the top item with Text =  "--Select--" and Value = ""
which will post a blank value for CityIDs and cause an error in ModelState.